# Get-Mailboxpermission for list of Mailboxes

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I want to get a list of all permissions for a specified list of mailboxes.

To get all permissions for just one, I can do this:

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity "Mailbox01"
```

What if I wanted to get a list of permissions for more than one mailbox at a time?

Something like:

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Identity "Mailbox01","Mailbox02","Mailbox03"
```

How could I do something like that - in one list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
"Mailbox01","Mailbox02","Mailbox03" | % { Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $_ }
```

Have to use a foreach because `Get-MailboxPermission` doesn't accept `[string[]]` as pipeline input or you can do:

```
"Mailbox01","Mailbox02","Mailbox03" | get-mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first pull a list of the mailboxes needed and pipe into a variable or paste into a .CSV file (I prefer CSV files).
Example:

```
Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited   | Where-Object {$_.RecipientType -like "UserMailbox"} | select userprincipalname, ForwardingAddress |out-gridview

$CSV = import-csv "c:\CSV.csv"

$CSV |out-gridview 

$CSV | foreach {get-MailboxPermission -identity $_.userprincipalname} |out-gridview
```

with the Gridview you can then further sort on multiple values