# Exchange 2010: How can I check what permissions a user/mailbox has towards other mailboxes?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I know how to check who has Full Access or Send As permissions on a specific mailbox, but how can I check if a specific user has Full Access or Send As permissions on any mailbox?

Comment: I dont think this really needs to be closed but a simple approach that should have been considered is looping all mailboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running Get-MailboxPermission cmdlet you can check which user/mailbox has what type of permissions to access other mailboxes in Exchange.

Check this helpful. And I'm sure it is what you was looking for.
http://exchangeserverpro.com/list-users-access-exchange-mailboxes/

And I also check this helpful
[Get-Mailboxpermission for list of Mailboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210923/get-mailboxpermission-for-list-of-mailboxes)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by user the following powershell command:
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -User 'username'

The problem i run into that this doesn't include 'Security Groups' with mailbox permissions that a user might be member of.

If anyone knows how to solve this i would highly appreciate a reply.

Answer (score 0):

Actually John Dane's answer is correct...it works for groups as well.  The -User parameter accepts DistinguishedName or SamAccountName...both of which AD Security Groups have.

So just pass it the SamAccountName (or 'username') of your group and your golden. I used this to find out which mailbox an old group we were thinking about retiring had permissions to.  I added a "| ft -autosize" to see the full identity field of the mailbox in the default output.

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -User 'SamAccountName'| ft -autosize
```

or just select the identity and access rights if that's all you need.

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxPermission -User 'SamAccountName'| select Identity,AccessRights | ft -autosize
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following Command you don't have any missing entries:

```
Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | Where {(!$_.isinherited) -and ($_.user.SecurityIdentifier -ne "S-1-5-10") -and  ($_.accessrights -contains "fullaccess")  } | Select Identity,User | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\testmailboxpermissions.csv"
```

Comment: Could you please format your code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K